# How do I connect a Magento database and a cloned repository on my local machine?

Tags: database, magento2.1.6, repository

I am working with a magento 2 build via a repository clone.  I have the dumped sql database from the repository build.  I imported the sql into my localhost DB, how do I connect them so that a local build is on my local?

Also, I can't find any good documentation on working with Magento via git repository fashion. Anyone have good resources they would like to share?

Answer (score 1):

Goto magento root `app\etc\env.php` set database

```
 'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'yourdatabasename',
        'username' => 'mysqlusername',
        'password' => 'mysqlpassword',
        'active' => '1',
      )
```

also check what is the mode you are `'MAGE_MODE' => 'default'`

```
clear /var/cache , /var/generate, var/page_cache
```

First update both the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` URLs in `core_config_data`.

after config run this command in magento root folder
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`. 
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: There is no app/etc/env.php file currently.  Should I run the full setup at localhost/setup first, then replace?

Comment: yes you can do :)